# uialertview with condition if statement in ios

Tags: ios, uialertview, conditional-statements

I have problem on `alertview` when I am trying to display some text if the user cancel the `alertivew`.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    UIALertView alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Answer"
                                             message:@"Your text"
                                                  delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [alert show]

    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"ok");
        [[self sectionSelectedDisplay] setText:answerLabel];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Comment: So you want to NSlog the index of the alertview button pressed?

Comment: The issue is not clear. What do you exactly need help for?

Comment: @Puneet: I edited the code. That my function. this [[self sectionSelectedDisplay] setText:answerLabel]; is notworking inside the if statement.

Comment: Because I want to run the code [[self sectionSelectedDisplay] setText:answerLabel]; after the user press "OK"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a function in UIalertviewdelegate as

if you have two button then function works as follows

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (buttonIndex == 1) {
      // this is normal button 
   }    
   else if (buttonIndex == 0) {
      // this is cancel button 
   }
}
```